# Best way to Convert Integer to Word

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, integer, cpu-word

What is the best way to convert an `integer` variable to `word`?

I have the `integer` variable `Competencia.Ano`
and the `word` variable `YearOf(TFilialTabelaProcessosAdministrativosJudiciais(ListaProcessos[index]).InicioValidadeEvento))`

i need to compare the both, How can I change type for both?

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. `YearOf` returns a `word` variable, which is the problem?

Comment: @Fabrizio, i have changed the question..

Comment: Which is the error message you're getting?

Comment: You don't need to convert integer to word. Instead assign word var to integer one. But in the most cases you can just compare word and integer (compiler will extend word for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for converting `integer` to `word` for comparing.

An `Integer` has an range of `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

An `Word` only from `0` to `65,535`

If you try to assign an `Integer` to an `Word` it will be bitclipt!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Var1 : Integer;
    Var2,
    Var3 : Word;
begin
 Var1 := 131071;
 Var2 :=  65535;
 if Var1 = Var2
  then MessageDlg('Var1 = Var2 ('+IntToStr(Var1)+' = '+IntToStr(Var2)+')'  ,mtInformation,[mbOK],0)
  else MessageDlg('Var1 <> Var2 ('+IntToStr(Var1)+' <> '+IntToStr(Var2)+')',mtInformation,[mbOK],0); // <--

 Var3 := Var1;
 if Var2 = Var3
  then MessageDlg('Var2 = Var3 ('+IntToStr(Var2)+' = '+IntToStr(Var3)+')'  ,mtInformation,[mbOK],0) // <--
  else MessageDlg('Var2 <> Var3 ('+IntToStr(Var2)+' <> '+IntToStr(Var3)+')',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;
```

In the first IF **Var1** and **Var2** are obviously not the same.

The **Var1** `Integer` (4 Bytes) is then assigned to the **Var3** `Word` (2 Bytes). The upper 2 Bytes of the `Integer` are clipt of so the second IF is true!

Comment: Mot sure what bitclipt means. I don't think that there will be clipping. I'm not sure what your example is meant to show. And what about the answer to the question? How do you compare integer and word?